# Sorted json array field

Tags: mysql, json, mysql-json

Is there a function in mysql to sort a `json` field?

```
SELECT new FROM mytable
["orange", "apple"]
```

==> Sorting the json array

```
SELECT SORTED(new) FROM mytable
["apple", "orange"]
```

Comment: I don't think so. All the JSON functions are listed [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-functions.html)

Comment: I see lots of questions from you about MySQL JSON. Just because this is available, I don't think you should overuse it. It would be better if you normalized your schema using traditional SQL design.

Comment: @Barmar right, yea this is a denormalized field of another table that we use on a `ListAll()` call, so we're storing a denormalized json field to improve read performance, etc...

Comment: @Barmar do you think there would a way to do this by perhaps unnesting the array and then nesting it again?

Comment: I don't know a way of unnesting the array in MySQL. Don't use JSON for this kind of thing. If it were in a normalized table you could use `ORDER BY`.

Comment: It's not MySQL, but Couchbase N1QL has such a function, ARRAY_SORT(); https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/arrayfun.html#fn-array-sort